# Why would AirPods on their own start tracking another person's device?

Tags: ios, find-my-iphone, airpods, find-my

Is it possible for AirPods to think on their think that they are "lost" and start tracking its location even if the owner hasn't triggered a "Find My" search?

Someone I was hanging out with recently was notified that their phone/location was being tracked by an "item." This alert popped up while we were together. After an hour of searching, we found that my AirPods were the culprit. But what's interesting is that I never triggered a search for them, so I am curious as to why it started tracking that person's device. I never received a notification or alert that the AirPods were missing or were monitoring someone.

Apple's documentation is not helpful regarding this matter. Has this happened to anyone, or has an understanding of why this would happen?

Comment: Why would *your* AirPods track *your friend's* iPhone?

Comment: @Thinkr Yes, that's the question, sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: Are your AirPods a recognized device on your friend's iPhone?

Comment: @Thinkr she never connected to my AirPods in any way so that's what's even more scary.

Comment: It is indeed; because if her phone had been connected to your AirPods, the culprit would be the [FindMy network](https://support.apple.com/guide/airpods/turn-find-network-supported-airpods-dev0742b9ff3/web#:~:text=Note%3A%20If%20people%20use%20your,AirPods%20are%20traveling%20with%20you.) but since her phone had never been connected to your AirPods...

Comment: Also, how did you come to the conclusion that it was your AirPods that were tracking her iPhone?

Comment: @Thinkr because when we went near my AirPods we saw the "play sound" feature and mine played some sound.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145811/discussion-between-captain-kirk-and-thinkr).

Comment: I prefer to continue it here if you don't mind. Doesn't the "play sound feature" indicate that the AirPods had managed to connect to your iPhone?

Comment: @Thinkr yes but she said she never went through the phone to connect to them. But the sound plays because the airpod was tracking her. To be clear this sound was a generic sound, not music on her phone.

Comment: But you told me that "mine played some sound". Was it her iPhone, not yours? Also, were the AirPods connected to your phone when hers made the sound?

Comment: @Thinkr To clarify. My AirPods played a sound. So this is what happened. When her phone came close to my AirPods, it showed on the screen that the tracking device was the AirPods and to confirm it's that AirPod case it showed a button that when tapped would play a sound on the AirPods. This is a safety feature so you can realize what was tracking you. My AirPods were in the case at the time she received the notification but the tracking had started 3-4 hours earlier (as per the alert on her phone).

Comment: And at the time the tracking had started, we were near each other when the AirPods were connected to my phone with one AirPod in my ear and the other in my AirPod case that was on me at the time.

Comment: Alright, thanks for explaining. Could you try to disable bluetooth on your iPhone and on your friend's iPhone (leave the AirPods on) and see if it still happens.

Comment: Waiting for them to come back so I can do this test. I'll keep you posted. Thanks!!

Comment: You tell me! Yw! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a security feature to ensure you weren't using your AirPods as a tracking device for your friend.

[What to do if you get an alert that an AirTag, Find My network accessory, or set of AirPods is with you (Apple)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212227):

> Unwanted tracking
>
> If any AirTag, AirPods, or other Find My network accessory separated from its owner is seen moving with you over time, you'll be notified in one of two ways. These features were created specifically to discourage people from trying to track you without your knowledge.

Comment: Cool feature and nice find!  This is good info to know

Comment: @JBallin thanks, but the main question now is why it started to track them since it wasn't initiated by me.

Comment: It's automatic. There's nothing to initiate.